# In PHP how to find the address of an USB device on the same machine?

Tags: php, shell, xampp, usb

I am in XAMMP PHP running on a windows 10 machine. I want to access a read-only USB device on the **same** machine, using something like fsockopen(), or file_get_contents(). But for this I need the address of the USB device.
I already googled a lot on shell_exec() or system(), but not found the appropriate commands, or they don't give any results.
Thanks to see :-)

Comment: i don't think there is such function to directly interface PHP to your usb device, you could however use the underlying windows commands to do that.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am trying to do, presumably with shell commands